# How to fix app.bundle.js Failed to load resource in Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-view, ionic-native

I am using below configurations for my ionic app:

```
Ionic CLI v1.2.1
Cordova 7.0.1
node v6.10.3
npm 3.10.10
```

On executing ionic serve, the web page opens blank with below error on console:

```
app.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status
```

It will be really helpful if someone can help me resolving this issue.

My package.json is :

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.5",
    "@angular/tsc-wrapped": "^4.2.5",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^1.3.12",
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.15",
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.1",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "ionic": "^1.2.1",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-beta.6",
    "ionic-native": "^1.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova": "1.4.0",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-gulp": "1.0.1",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "1.3.1",
    "del": "2.2.0",
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "gulp-watch": "4.3.5",
    "ionic-gulp-browserify-typescript": "^1.1.0",
    "ionic-gulp-fonts-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-html-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-sass-build": "^1.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-scripts-copy": "^1.0.1",
    "run-sequence": "1.1.5"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard",
    "cordova-plugin-datepicker",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation",
    "cordova-plugin-spinner-dialog"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    "ios",
    "android"
  ],
  "name": "ionic-staffind",
  "description": "ionic-staffind: An Ionic project"
}
```

Comment: You are using ionic 1 right?

Comment: @Emeka Yes, it is.